# heroku rake db:migrate ERROR "gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mysql2

im using Rails 3.2.6 trying to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

i get the adaptar ERROR

```
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

in my **database.yml** i have development, production, and test set to:

```
adapter: mysql2
```

this is my **gem env**

```
➜  my_app git:(master) gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-11-10 patchlevel 327) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327
     - /Users/jcollyer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

i have tried a few things i found googling, no luck.  any help appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Heroku's platform is tightly coupled with Postgres and they do not offer MySQL databases as an option without provisioning an add-on. Are you using a MySQL add-on or remote host?

Comment: Off Topic: rails 3.2.6 has major security issues - upgrade to 3.2.13 or higher - see https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aweblog.rubyonrails.org&q=CVE rails blog posts for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku, your best option for a database is postgresql, hands down. There are a handful of reasons that boil down to: that's how Heroku was designed to work.

If you're simply using the rails orm you can use the mysql2psql gem in your development environment and change your config files to use postgresql in production.

If you're really married to mysql for whatever reason, you'll need to install a heroku addon to get your app up and running. There are a couple options but here's one: https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb

But really, your best bet is to migrate your app to postgresql, it's worth it.

More info here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-mysql

Answer (score 7):

Remember that Heroku uses the config property DATABASE_URL instead of your database.yml file for connecting to your db.  Make sure it is set.  If you are using the ClearDB add-on, then the value you want should be in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL.

```
heroku config
```

Copy the value that ClearDB will have set for you in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL config variable.  Set the DATABASE_URL to the same value

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=mysql2://bb06ca765fb123:71b6dabc@us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com/heroku_703eded6aebc123?reconnect=true
```

Here's the catch.  Most people are using the mysql2 gem, so you typically need to set the DATABASE_URL to mysql2... instead of mysql.

There's no need to abandon mysql and migrate to postgre.

Comment: I tried everything else, and this was the cause. You're the man!